# Perform a Task on uninstallation of the application in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application and I am adding events in the calendar when user logs in. and removing the events when user logs out.
But I also want to perform a task of removing the events when user uninstall my application.

This question has already been asked by others but did not get the perfect solution.

If you know any other alternate solution then please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do that. The app being uninstalled can not perform any task regarding that.

Comment: Ok. But any other alternate solution to delete events from calendar? @RiyazAhamed

Answer (score 0):

That is not supported. Your app's code is not run when it is being uninstalled.

Comment: ok sir. But is there a alternate solution to execute some task before apps get uninstalled? for example using some broadcast receiver ?

Comment: @chetan: "But is there a alternate solution to execute some task before apps get uninstalled?" -- I hope not. Malware authors would be very happy to have an option here.